# HTMLImageElement onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an onclick event that calls a function selectMain(name). When I run my project it doesn't seem to generate the onclick attribute from the image.

```
function previewFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    if (/\.(jpe?g|png)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var image = new Image();
        image.height = 100;
        image.title = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;
        image.onclick = selectMain(file.name);
        preview.appendChild(image);
      }, false);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
  }
}
```

```
function selectMain(name) {
  var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;
  Array.from(files).forEach(file => {
    if (file.name == name) {
      document.getElementById("primaryPhoto").value = file;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `previewFiles()` is being called? If so,
are you sure that `readAndPreview(file)` is being called? if so, 
are you sure that the if statement with your regex `/\.(jpe?g|png)$/i.test(file.name)` is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what *Gagik* answered (the early `selectMain` call is definitiely *an* issue even if it doesn't fix the whole thing), what is

```
document.getElementById("primaryPhoto").value = file;
```

supposed to do? If `primaryPhoto` is a `input[type=file]` element, then that won't work due to security limitations

> You cannot set the value of a file picker from a script

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Notes).

Comment: What I am trying to achieveis an image uploader that shows a preview of the pictures, if you would click on them I want add it to a hidden inputfield so i can do something with the selected file in a controller(asp.net)

Comment: I don't have much experience in asp.net but I think you need to set the _name_ of the selected file to the hidden input field and then in the backend side of things check the uploaded files in your input[type=file] and find the selected file based on the selected filename. Kind of what you did in `selectMain` but do it in C# instead.

Comment: I followed your advice to only send the name through a hidden field and then in c# if(file.Name == hiddenInputField){
      //do stuff
}

Answer (score 2):

Try this`image.onclick = function(){ selectMain(file.name); };`

Comment: The problem in your code is  then you write like that  `image.onclick = selectMain(file.name);` your selectMain function is being called in the line in which you want to attach it to onclick event. You must attach onclick event a definition of function or the name of function but now call it with brackets. But if you want to give function argument you must create new function ( ex. without name like I mentioned above ) and in that call your function with argument

Answer (score 0):

```
(/\.(jpeg?g|png)$/i.test(file.name))
```

Comment: Please do not forget to explain why your answer is a probable answer to the poster's question :)

Answer (score 0):

In the existing code, function get invoked on the time of render on dom.

here is the correct way to bind event.

```
   var image = new Image();
       image.height = 100;
       image.title = file.name;
       image.src = this.result;
       image.onclick =()=>{selectMain(file.name)};
```